# Linux Mint not shutting down Mac

Tags: linux, mac, linux-mint

Yesterday I installed the new Linux distro, Linux Mint 15 on my Mac. Everything is running fine, but when i want to shut my latop down, the fans and the keyboard-backlight keep running! Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Are you mounting any network shares? Try disconnecting your network before shutting down, does that solve it?

Comment: How are you shutting down? From the gui? From the terminal? Try running `init 0` from the command line?

Comment: it was a problem with the screen driver, its already solved!